# Collision between subview and an outside view Swift

Tags: swift, view, swift3, collision

I am creating a game in which a ball (view) hits a different view(paddle) with ten subviews within it(paddle). The subviews, programmatically created, all fit within the view so there is no empty space. I have conditionals set up to change the push direction of the ball depending on the subview that it hits.

In my collision behavior function, I set the array of subviews to the item2.isEqual property. But after a lot of debugging, I figured out that the ball never collides with the subviews within the paddle view. Is there a way for the ball to hit them and not the view that contains them?

Side note... I am not using SpriteKit.

Comment: Not clear from your question, but are you using the `UICollisionBehavior` class in your code?

Comment: Yes, I have the delegate. Sorry for not mentioning that.